# Mybatis sqlSession.commit not work when MYSQL set AUTOCOMMIT=0

Tags: transactions, commit, mybatis

I'm using springboot + mybatis + MYSQL(innodb)

When I set MYSQL autocommit=0, and doing transaction in my code. I found the transaction is not committed. Following are my code:

data source:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zzzz?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=yyyy
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Mybatis transaction config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyBatisConfiguration {

    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

And my Service to do transaction:

```
@Service
public class AlohaService {

    @Autowired private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public void customizedSqlSessionInsert() {
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        UserRoleMapper userRoleMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserRoleMapper.class);
        try {
            userRoleMapper.insert(new UserRole(0, "RRRRR", "ADMIN"));
            sqlSession.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sqlSession.rollback();
        } finally {
            sqlSession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

After execute `customizedSqlSessionInsert` method, I find that select record doesn't contains new row `RRRR,ADMIN`, Interesting thing is that after I run a `COMMIT` command on MySQL GUI Tool, the record appears in MySQL.

Why the `sqlSession.commit();` not work? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

When `spring-mybatis` is used for mybatis-spring integration (and it is used by spring-boot) then commit/rollback methods on session are effectively no-op methods as transactions are managed by spring. That is spring knows when to start and finish transaction and how to finish it (e.g. if exception is thrown transaction is rolled back etc).

All operations related to transactions are handled by the implementation of `org.apache.ibatis.transaction.Transaction` which in the default configuration of mybatis-spring is `SpringManagedTransaction`.

Here's from [SpringManagedTransaction](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/transaction/SpringManagedTransaction.html) javadoc:

> If Spring's transaction handling is active it will no-op all commit/rollback/close calls assuming that the Spring transaction manager will do the job.

Comment: What about Connection.commit?

Comment: If you invoke `commit` on the native `Connection` used by spring of cause it will commit the transaction but you don't want to do that as such commit will mess the spring transaction management that is spring wouldn't know about such commit and would still `think` that transaction is not committed and may eventually try to rollback it (if for example some exception happens later).